# Parsing xml document with spanish special characters

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding

I have an xml document which contains data in Spanish. The document is encoded as ISO-8859-1. The special characters in Spnish appeared as numbers, eg, 363, 355, 341, etc. So some words look like: te363ricas, caracter355sticas and so on. When I try to parse the data, I get invalid character error.

My php script which parses the data expects utf8 data. I already tried to convert the data using utf8_encode(), mb_convert_encoding() and iconv() but none of them worked.

If I see the file in VIM, then those special characters showed up correctly, but when I see the output from less command in terminal, those numbers shows up instead of the characters.

Here is some portion extracted from the file:

Copied from VIM

> Conocer las diferentes aproximaciones teóricas al envejecimiento y sus características más relevantes.
>   - Identificar las aspectos más importantes sobre los que planificar la actividad de animación.
>   - Desarrollar los conocimientos necesarios con los que debe contar el animador para desarrollar la actividad adecuadamente.

Copied from LESS command output

> Conocer las diferentes aproximaciones te363ricas al envejecimiento y sus caracter355sticas m341s relevantes.
>   - Identificar las aspectos m341s importantes sobre los que planificar la actividad de animaci363n.
>   - Desarrollar los conocimientos necesarios con los que debe contar el animador para desarrollar la actividad adecuadamente.

Here is the code snippet:

```
$fp = fopen('data.xml', 'r');

$parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_set_element_handler($parser, 'start_element', 'end_element');
xml-set_character_data_handler($parser, 'character_data');
while(!feof($fp)) {
  $data = fgets($fp, 16384);
  if(!xml_parse($parser, $data, feof($fp))) {
    $error = 'xml file contains error on line     '.xml_get_current_line_number($parser).
      'with following problem     '.xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($parser));
    die($error);
  }
}

function start_element($parser, $name, $attrs) {
  // something to do with the start element
}

function end_element($parser, $name, $attrs) {
  // something to do with end element
}

function character_data($parser, $data) {
  // something to do with the data
}
```

And here is sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<programas>
<programa id="1">
<objetivos><![CDATA[- Conocer las diferentes aproximaciones te363ricas     al envejecimiento y sus caracter355sticas m341s relevantes.
- Identificar las aspectos m341s importantes sobre los que planificar la     actividad de animaci363n.
- Desarrollar los conocimientos necesarios con los que debe contar el     animador para desarrollar la actividad adecuadamente.]]></objetivos>
</programa>
</programas>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have an encoding specification at the beginning of your XML (I mean, something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>`)? Is the physical file correctly encoded? Can you post a snippet of your file?

Comment: Hi, yes, the document contains encoding specification as you mentioned in iso-8859-1, I already mentioned in my question also (the second line). Sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: @potame: I am not sure if the physical file is correctly encoded, I will check that. One more thing may be helpful to know is - those characters shows correctly in VIM but shows those characters as numbers if I use LESS command to see the file in command line. Please see my updated question.

Comment: pls post a minimum valid example from your XML, as well as a minimum working code.

Comment: @sparrow doesn't look like an xml problem. I'd look for posts about encoding. Re-tag your question to attract encoding professionals. I've close to no idea about encoding, but are you sure that it is a correct encoding in your xml?

Comment: You seem to be using an incorrect tool to copy and paste the example text.  The string `m341s` is five characters with three ASCII digit characters in the middle.  Probably it should be `m\341s` where the escape sequence `\341` represents a single byte, presumably with the octal value 0341 (decimal 225, hex E1) which is indeed the character code for á in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Character encoding in PHP is messy but by quick glance, `$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1")` should do what you want.  Not sure about the 16384-byte chunking but that's irrelevant as far as decoding from a single-byte encoding is concerned.